# Mongodb authentication shell/ console

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell

I have a Node JS program, which uses Mongo DB as my dbs. Now... everyone can access the mongo shell with no issues at all.

Is this how it is meant to be? I want to keep the mongo shell away from anyone else, i.e. you have to authenticate before using the shell.The reason being is that I dont want people deleting tables in the database, and insert/ modifying documents through the console.

Is there a way to do this? I had a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/security/ However I am not sure how to implement this to my Node Js program (keeping the password a secret).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A few solutions :

- Restrict access to your db to only the required IP addresses. If your app and database are on the same machine, that would be 127.0.0.1 only + maybe your PC so you can run queries in a GUI.
- enforce authentication as in [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/), with a strong password.
  To keep the password 'secret' in your Node program, which I understand as "not hardcoded", make it an env variable and give it to node at runtime, or write it in a file that doesn't live in your repo (.gitignore works too).

With a valid user/password, here's how to authenticate to mongodb using Node :

A mongodb address has 7 components :

```
    protocol:"mongodb://",
    host:"localhost",
    user: "user",
    password : "password",
    options: "?authMechanism=MONGODB-CR",
    port:"27017",
    db:"db_name"
```

Which all together give a string like :

`mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/db_name?authMechanism=MONGODB-CR`,

That should be enough for Node to connect using the native Mongo driver.

And to authenticate in the shell :

> use db_name
>
> db.auth("user", "password" )

or, directly on connection :

`mongo -u "user" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "db_name"`